# Evaluate Fetch Api in PuppeteerSharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

What is the c# alternative of the java code below?

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  return fetch('url', {method: 'POST', body: 'test' });
});
```

I need to send a post request using PuppeteerSharp. There are several ways but it seems it is the easiest one, But I did not find any alternative for the fetch method.

for the `evaluate` method I found this method `await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync` for C#, but How can I use fetch inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Puppeteer, the function that we provide to `page.evaluate` is executed in context of the page and so it has to be a JavaScript function.

Likewise, in the equivalent functions in puppeteer-sharp e.g. [page.EvaluateFunctionAsync](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Page.html#PuppeteerSharp_Page_EvaluateFunctionAsync__1_System_String_System_Object___), the first argument is a string which is nothing but a JavaScript function.
You should be able to use the fetch as it is, something like:

```
await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync(@"() => {
  return fetch('url', {method: 'POST', body: 'test' });
}");
```